# How do I add a model binder in asp.net mvc from a method called by Application_Start?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a modelbinder being added during Application_Start like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        // Model Binding
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SessionUser), new SessionUserModelBinder());
        ////////////////

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

I would like the `Application_Start` method to call a separate method to add my custom model binder to the list like:

```
namespace NewNameSpace
{
    public class TestStartClass
    {
        public static void AppStart()
        {
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SessionUser), new SessionUserModelBinder());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try this, `Binder` in `ModelBinders.Binder` returns an error which says:

```
Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders' does not contain a definition for 'Binder'
```

I am `using System.Web.Mvc`. What am I missing that's preventing this from working?

Comment: Are you using `ModelBinders.Binder` (which doesn't exist) instead of `ModelBinders.Binders` somewhere? The error message suggests you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you must have a typo in your code.  The error message is saying you are trying to reference a class member like `ModelBinders.Binder`.  You need that to be `ModelBinders.Binders.Add()`.

[ModelBinders.Binders Property MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinders.binders.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The error message says ModelBinders does not have a `Binder` property and that's correct.  It has a `Binders` property (note the s).